# T-SQL multiple inserts with calculated primary key

Tags: t-sql

I wrote a script against SQL 2008 which worked fine:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PK_COLUMN),0) + 1
FROM ITEM_TABLE), 'Data 1', @HeadSeq)
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PK_COLUMN),0) + 1
FROM ITEM_TABLE), 'Data 2', @HeadSeq)
...
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PK_COLUMN),0) + 1
FROM ITEM_TABLE), 'Data 73', @HeadSeq)
```

However in 2005 it gives this error for each line:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Is there a better way of solving this rather than doing the following? (which would would make slotting one in the middle difficult)

```
DECLARE @SequenceCounter INT
SELECT @SequenceCounter = ISNULL(MAX(PK_COLUMN),0) FROM ITEM_TABLE

INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES(@SequenceCounter + 1, 'Data 1', @HeadSeq)

INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES(@SequenceCounter + 2, 'Data 2', @HeadSeq)
...
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE VALUES(@SequenceCounter + 73, 'Data 73', @HeadSeq)
```

I am aware this should be solved by first inserting the data into a table with an automatic primary key, and then transfer the data from one table to the other, I am looking for the best "script only" solution.

Thanks

Lee

Comment: I've also considered before each insert doing @SequenceCounter+1 on it's own, and then just using @SequenceCounter, I'm looking for a more elegant solution - if there is one!

Comment: Your proposed solution is kinda dangerous, unless you manually issue table locks - when you are executing statement 73, it's well possible that someone has inserted something in between, and you'll have a double key (or an error, if you have constraints on the key column)

Comment: Yes in that regard the second solution is dangerous, it works for me as the database is currently not used, but I'm looking for a better solution to use against SQL 2005 in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, subqueries weren't allowed in the `VALUES` list prior to SQL 2008. However there is an easy workarond:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM_TABLE 
SELECT TOP (1) 
    ISNULL(MAX(PK_COLUMN),0) + 1, 
    'Data 1', 
    @HeadSeq
FROM
    ITEM_TABLE
```

Comment: I don't think the 'top (1)' is necessary, but thanks for the solution.